# how to replace only certain certain digits in a pattern coming in a file

Tags: c#

I have a sorted Dictionary in C#, which has Dates joined with strings like "NA", "WD", "LD", "HD". It looks like.

10/01/2015 NA

10/02/2015 NA

10/03/2015 NA

10/04/2015 LD

10/05/2015 WD

10/06/2015 WD

10/07/2015 HD

10/08/2015 WD

10/09/2015 LD

10/10/2015 HD

10/11/2015 WD

10/12/2015 HD

10/13/2015 HD

10/14/2015 NA

10/15/2015 NA

10/16/2015 WD

10/17/2015 HD

10/18/2015 WD

Now, after processing this information, I will have result as follows.

10/01/2015NA    3

10/02/2015NA    3

10/03/2015NA    3

10/04/2015LD    3

10/05/2015WD    2

10/06/2015WD    2

10/07/2015HD    1 // I should get this changed to 2.

10/08/2015WD    2

10/09/2015LD    3

10/10/2015HD    1

10/11/2015WD    2

10/12/2015HD    1 //No change for this. because it does not appear between 2.

10/13/2015HD    1 //No change for this. because it does not appear between 2.

10/14/2015NA    3

10/15/2015NA    3

10/16/2015WD    2

10/17/2015HD    1 // I should get this changed to 2.

10/18/2015WD    2

I need to change any number 1 coming between 2. I tried my best to solve it. But nothing seems to be working out at all. I am desperate after almost 6 hours trying to do it. Since this is programming, there is definitely a solution but which eludes me.

Could anyone guide me please.

Comment: What is the key of that dictionary? and after the processing the data is still in dictionary?

Comment: the dictionary is defined as: SortedDictionary<string,string> sortedDictionary = new SortedDictionary<string,string>(); The data will be available in a text file.I only need the last number for my purposes.

Comment: I retrieve the information using sd.Key, and sd.Value.using a foreach loop.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Check for the answer i have posted.

Comment: Yes. please. I am doing it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Will this work for you ?**

```
SortedDictionary<string, string> Dates = new SortedDictionary<string, string>();
Dates.Add("1", "10/06/2015WD 2  ");
Dates.Add("2", "10/07/2015HD 1");
Dates.Add("3", "10/08/2015WD 2 ");
for(int i = 0; i < Dates.Count; i++)
 {
   string Key = Dates.ElementAt(i).Key;
   string CurrentValue = Dates.ElementAt(i).Value.Trim();
   string CurrentValueLastChar = CurrentValue.Substring(CurrentValue.Length - 1, 1);
   if (i - 1 != -1 && i + 1 < Dates.Count)
    {
      string PreviousValue = Dates.ElementAt(i - 1).Value.Trim();
      string NextValue = Dates.ElementAt(i + 1).Value.Trim();
      string PreviousValueLastChar = PreviousValue.Substring(PreviousValue.Length - 1, 1);
      string NextValueLastChar = NextValue.Substring(NextValue.Length - 1, 1);
      if (PreviousValueLastChar == NextValueLastChar)
           Dates[Key] = (Dates[Key].Remove(Dates[Key].Length - 1)) + PreviousValueLastChar;

    }                

 }
```

Comment: I am experimenting one by one. I am not an expert like both Mr. Waqar Ahmed and Backtrac. Thanks.

Comment: Your solution to the question I raised worked fine. It was a interesting piece of sharing of your knowledge. I have no words to thank you.